# NSURLSession set request timeout accurately

Tags: ios, timeout, nsurlsession

We set timeout interval for a request by `NSMutableURLRequest timeoutInterval`. As Apple's document described, it specifies **the limit between packets**, not the whole request. When we analyse our requests logs, some timeout request exceeded the seconds we set to timeoutInterval. We need timeout the requests accurately.

By reading document and blogs, the `timeoutIntervalForRequest` property in `NSURLSessionConfiguration` is the same as `timeoutInterval`. But the `timeoutIntervalForResource` property seems fit our requirement.

However, *Mattt* says in [objc.io](https://www.objc.io/issues/5-ios7/from-nsurlconnection-to-nsurlsession/) that `timeoutIntervalForResource` "*should only really be used for background transfers*". Can it be used in normal request? Such as query user info. Is it appropriate in this situation?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It **can** be used, but it rarely makes sense to do so.

The expected user experience from an iOS app is that when the user asks to download or view some web-based resource, the fetch should continue, retrying/resuming as needed, until the user explicitly cancels it.

That said, if you're talking about fetching something that isn't requested by the user, or if you are fetching additional optional data that you can live without, adding a resource timeout is probably fine.  I'm not sure why you would bother to cancel it, though.  After all, if you've already spent the network bandwidth to download half of the data, it probably makes sense to let it finish, or else that time is wasted.

Instead, it is usually better to time out any UI that is blocked by the fetch, if applicable, but continue fetching the request and cache it.  That way, the next time the user does something that would cause a similar fetch to occur, you already have the data.

The only exception I can think of would be fetching video fragments or something similar, where if it takes too long, you need to abort the transfer and switch to a different, lower-quality stream.  But in most apps, that should be handled by the HLS support in iOS itself, so you don't have to manage that.

Comment: Thanks a lot. We are developing an iOS SDK. The log of requests in it is collected to server to analyze the error rate. When the request runs out of the time we set, which happens in weak network sometimes, it should disconnect the connection to server timely. Or the server will be occupied by these low speed TCP connections.

Comment: Got it.  Yeah, then feel free to use the resource timeout.  It should work.  And of course, if it doesn't work for any reason, you can always use a timer and cancel the task.